# using ResponseType attribute in swagger

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger

I am using swagger for my webapi2 documentation. i downloaded the source code from github and trying to change the source code according to my requirement.But i am facing a problem with response type that is, i want to specify responsetype attribute on one of my get method so i used  `[ResponseType(typeof(List<Student>))]` (student is my class and i want to return student properties in model schema), but it is returning `IHttpActionResult` as model and null value as model schema in documentation, is there any other way to access the responsetype attribute in the code so that i can return the properties of my model...

please help me out...

```
[ResponseType(typeof(List<Student>))]
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        { //my code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When we want to use custom attributes which are defined on our  methods we need to access the attribute like this

```
var responseType = actionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<ourattributename>();
```

in my case the attribute is `ResponseTypeAttribute`

so now in `responseType` you will be getting the returntype of the method.
And then code changes can be done accordingly based on the returnType and our requirement in `Swagger.Net.XmlCommentDocumentationProvider`.

please let me know if you have any issue regarding this.

Thanks.